# How to use forms.ChoiceField() inside ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I want to show a dropdownlist in my form by using the ModelForm. My code added below-

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CreateUserForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['name', 'age']
    AGE_CHOICES = (('10', '15', '20', '25', '26', '27', '28'))
    age = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(choices=AGE_CHOICES)
    )
```

It's not showing dropdownlist in the form. Also, I want "Select" selected as default with empty value. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fields shouldn't be part of the meta class, simply just unindent it back to the class level

Comment: Is **grade** a field of User model,or you wrote grade in the place of age as a mistake.?

Comment: Sorry, it was by mistake! updated already. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modified your code.Try this :

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CreateUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'age')
        AGE_CHOICES = (
                ('', 'Select an age'),
                ('10', '10'), #First one is the value of select option and second is the displayed value in option
                ('15', '15'),
                ('20', '20'),
                ('25', '25'),
                ('26', '26'),
                ('27', '27'),
                ('28', '28'),
                )
         widgets = {
            'age': forms.Select(choices=AGE_CHOICES,attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```