# Create an integer field with a drop down box. Django Custom Widget?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create an integer field connected with a drop down box to collect a time period from a user. From there i would like to store it in a table in some sort of readable format for the machine e.g 12W from that i can split the object and add 12 weeks on to todays date and fill a Due Date field.

For example

```
[12][Days]
    [weeks]
    [Months]
```

Would this be a customer widget? or is there a better way of completed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just a form you could use 2 form fields, both of which are already present in Django, and their default widgets.

[IntegerField (forms)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) + [ChoiceField (forms)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices) something like `[[0, "Days"],[1, "Weeks"],[2, "Months"],]`

So it would look like:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Your name')
    units = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[[0, "Days"],[1, "Weeks"],[2, "Months"],])
```

If you want a model to store these 2 values separately, you could use ([IntegerField (models)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#integerfield) and some field of your preference with [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices)). Then use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), so you will not need to define any fields on your form anymore.

In case you want even more machine-frieldly format than 2 separate values... Check whether your database can store intervals and consider using [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield). However you will lose the possibility to automatically create neat form with 2 widgets.

Comment: hey, thanks for replying i made a MultivalueField out of a interger field and a char field with choices set :) thanks again.

Comment: @AllDay you used a different approach to solve it. Please consider providing [an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accepting your own answer instead :)

Comment: its not 100% yet, i cannot seem to get the widget to render on the form, I have set up a codeshare if you would like to take a look. It looks like it should work to me but im still getting a basic text input. https://codeshare.io/2KoL6P -- Code is on this page

Comment: @AllDay That's because the default widget of `MultiValueField` is `TextInput` (see the [documentation 3rd line](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield))

Comment: @AllDay Here, found an example of how you should implement custom widgets for the `MultiValueField` :) https://gist.github.com/elena/3915748

Answer (score 0):

`INT_CHOICES = [(x, x) for x in range(1, 60)]`

in the model:

`date_interval = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=INT_CHOICES, default=1)`

in the model form:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['x1', 'x2'..., 'date_interval']
    widgets = {'date_interval': forms.Select(choices=INT_CHOICES)
```

and that should do the trick.

I am a little surprised that the "forms.ChoiceField" in the answer above can works. See [how to use forms choicefield inside modelform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885866/how-to-use-forms-choicefield-inside-modelform).